# How can I combine a line chart with a table of raw data like Excel does

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working on making a line chart like this, which is generated with Excel.

[image: Line Chart with data]

Is it possible to render a chart like above with highcharts?

Here is my progress for now:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    marginBottom: 150,
    marginLeft: 150,
    width: 600,
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Chart Title'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  yAxis: {
    max: 100
  },

  legend: {
    width: '100',
    height: 'auto',
    floating: true,
    align: 'left',
    y: 10,
    itemWidth: 100,
    borderWidth: 1
  },

  series: [{
    data: [31, 86, 8, 22, 35, 78, 63, 19, 7, 42, 41, 40],
    name: 'First'
  }, {
    data: [74, 77, 100, 25, 70, 72, 16, 61, 55, 88, 52, 88],
    name: 'Second'
  }, {
    data: [52, 93, 68, 5, 66, 79, 66, 41, 5, 55, 41, 49],
    name: 'Third'
  }, {
    data: [23, 23, 75, 28, 42, 10, 48, 96, 98, 8, 32, 72],
    name: 'Fourth'
  }, {
    data: [34, 68, 89, 98, 69, 46, 31, 47, 29, 24, 87, 59],
    name: 'Fifth'
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

The problem is that I have no idea about how to embed raw data in chart and align the data with lines.

Comment: take a look at this topic: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=9062&p=150268&hilit=table#p150276 is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I'd like to make the data align with lines properly and the legend be the title of data as attached. It seems not exactly what I need but would be a good reference. Thank you for commenting.